# Почему Laravel 8, не видит данные в config/services.php?

Tags: laravel

Делаю авторизацию, для это использую Socialite Providers.

В доке написано, что надо в файл config/services.php указать массив данных приложения, я это сделал:

```
 'yandex' => [    
    'client_id' => env('my'),  
    'client_secret' => env('my'),  
    'redirect' => env('http://localhost/aaa') 
    ],
```

И вызывать таким способом

```
use Laravel\Socialite\Facades\Socialite;
 
Route::get('/auth/redirect', function () {
    return Socialite::driver('github')->redirect();
});
 
Route::get('/auth/callback', function () {
    $user = Socialite::driver('github')->user();
 
});
```

Но у меня таким способом, почему-то не видит данные в массиве config/services.php, пишет, что Отсутствует обязательный параметр 'client_id', и мне приходится делать таким способом, каждый раз устанавливать конфиг и только так работает, почему?

```
Route::get('/', function () {

    $clientId = "myId";
    $clientSecret = "mySecret";
    $redirectUrl = "http://localhost/aaa";
    
    $config = new \SocialiteProviders\Manager\Config($clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUrl);
   
    return Socialite::driver('yandex')->setConfig($config)->redirect();
    
    
});

Route::get('/aaa', function(){
    
    $clientId = "myId";
    $clientSecret = "mySecret";
    $redirectUrl = "http://localhost/aaa";

    $config = new \SocialiteProviders\Manager\Config($clientId, $clientSecret, $redirectUrl);
    
    $user = Socialite::driver('yandex')->setConfig($config)->user();
    
    dd($user);
});
```

Вот таки способом, у меня работает, но получается очень много дублирования кода.

Answer (score -1):

Я разобрался, надо убрать функции env.

Comment: Нужно значения прописать в .env файл, и использовать их в конфиге под ключом в этом файле